# Eclipse - support for multiple editor perspectives

Tags: eclipse, ide

Is there an Eclipse shortcut to switch between multiple text editor configurations?

When using Eclipse, I typically have two editor tab configurations:

1. Side-by-side configuration. I keep the main class file on the left
   and the corresponding unit tests on the right.
2. Single-tab configuration. I view only one class file at a time in
   the editor.

I use #1 when at work, when my larger monitor allows me to see 100-column files side-by-side without horizontally scrolling.

I use #2 on my laptop when in transit (bus, plane, etc). My laptop is not wide enough to support side-by-side, so I only display one file at a time to avoid horizontally scrolling.

What I would really like is a way to switch configurations quickly. I often leave work with tons of tabs open in my workspace, which is very difficult to read when I open it on my laptop.

NOTE: Perspectives don't appear to solve this problem, since Editor configuration is constant across all perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that editors are not bound to perspectives like views are. Perspectives are collections of views, and optionally, a viewable editor area. However, which editor(s) are open at any time is something that's under the control of the workbench, and not the perspectives.

Nevertheless, a solution for your problem is discussed in the article
[Show / Hide Eclipse RCP Editors depending on the current Perspective](http://esalagea.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/show-hide-eclipse-rcp-editors-depending-on-the-current-perspective/).

The article is too long to reproduce here, but the steps it describes are:

1. Implement an Editors Tracker.
2. Implement a Perspective Listener, which will listen for perspective changed events and will show or hide the editors accordingly.
3. Subscribe the listener to the workbench.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Seems like a lot of work. For now, I'm just closing all windows (ctrl+shift+w) when I start a laptop session and just open the Resources I care about manually.

Comment: A lot of work because your demand wasn't foreseen for some unknown reason by the developers, so you have to extend the workbench yourself.